# How do I perform a private video search with the Vimeo access token access token but no idea how to use it

Tags: video, token, private, vimeo

How do I perform a private video search with Vimeo API and jQuery Ajax? I have the access token but no idea how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Private videos are not yet supported through search. This is consistent with Vimeo's on site search, and will be fixed in the future. Unfortunately there is no timeframe on that.